# Best way to reattach this molding to the drywall?

Tags: drywall, trim

We bought an old house earlier this year and the molding it loose in a lot of places. It looks like they used very long, thin nails to attach it originally. They don't seem very effective. How should we reattach the molding?[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "Long" is the key. They are far longer than necessary for drywall, and drywall by itself won't hold well. If you can line things up so those nails are going into the framing then thin nails should do just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that type of heavy softwood trim on drywall, I'd use 2-1/2" 16 gauge gun nails, or get some 2-1/2" hardened trim/casing nails (which are significantly narrower then regular wire nails) and pre-drill through just the trim with a 1/16" bit. You want an inch of penetration into the framing, at least.

Where it contacts the door jamb, 1-1/2" or 2" nails are adequate, but you could use the longer nails as well.

You can also use a few dabs of construction adhesive or silicone against the drywall for better stability.